# Refer cell value to range of cells on another sheet

Tags: excel, cell, formula, lookup, vlookup

Looking for a formula for specific range of values to a reference range on another sheet...

i.e.  if cell A1 sheet 1 contains a specific value, then i would like it to find that value on column A of sheet 2 and result with equivalent row value of column B

I have a range on sheet 2 showing temperatures in column A with equivalent adjustment values in column B to go with each particular temperature.

I would like a formula that automatically fills in the temperature adjustment value into cell K23 on sheet 1 when I input the temperature into cell J22 (to be more specific)

Thanks for any help in advance!!!!

Comment: Can you provide examples of data?

Comment: temps range from 25-106 in sheet 2 cells a1:a82
adjustments range from 1.0157 to 0.9791 in cells B1:B82

sheet 1 K23 is where i would like adjustment shown that matches the equivalent temp that i type into sheet 1 J22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some 'bare bones' code with some main concepts for you to start work with.
You will notice that you have received a number of downvotes for your Q.  This is likely becase the spirit of this site is for you to demonstrate that you have made some attempt and/or research to 'help yourself' before posting your Q.  For this reason I have not included any explanation.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("J22")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    adj = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B10"), 2, False)
        If IsError(adj) Then
            Range("K23") = 0
        Else
            Range("K23") = adj
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Well maybe this will help...i've attemped to use wildcards in association with the cell lookup reference. I've attempted to use index+match functions as well with no luck. The function argument of Lookup_Value J22 = "70" However the Formula Result = (blank)  I've attempted using absolute cell references, this changes nothing.
I've also searched for 3 hrs on this site, not finding a single instance of this particular problem.  I'm sorry if my original question didn't show my attempts at solving this problem on my own.

Comment: That's great Chris.  Understanding the culture, and including some of this in your Q, makes it more likely you will get a good response that's all.  So does it work for you and do you understand what is going on?  Perhaps a key bit of info is that this code should go into the Sheet module where you are using cell J22, and into its Worksheet_Change event!

Comment: Figured it out...my entire sheet is all number...yet somehow J22 was the only cell containing a number that was considered text. That was the problem..thanks for the help anyways.  Much appreciation!

Comment: @Chris Thats great - well done.  If the answer has answered your Q perhaps you would 'accept' it by clicking the 'tick' mark.  This indicates to others that an answer has been tendered and accepted.